# Display HTML while <option> is viable selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like the below:

```
<select name="blah">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

I want it such that the submit button only appears if the user has selected an option with `value >= 1` So on page load it will not display the submit button because the currently selected option has no `value`, but the moment a user selects a valid option, the submit button appears.

Is this something that can be accomplished with JS/JQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code in java script

```
function isSelected() {
  var value =document.getElementById("blah").selectedIndex;
  if(value >='1'){
    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.display='block';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.display='none';
  }
}
```

**Your HTML**

```
<select id="blah" onChange="isSelected();">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none" id="btnSubmit"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to display submit button when page loads then add below css

```
input[type=submit] {display:none;}
```

To show submit button on value changes try below js code

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        var value = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9-]/,""),10)
        if(value >= 1)
        {
            $('input[type=submit]').show();
        }
    });
});;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tfN6p/1/)**

Comment: As default option is disabled, this should be enough: `$('select').change(function () {
        $('input[type=submit]').show();
    });`

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(){
       if($('select[name="blah"]').val() > 1)
          $('#yourform').submit();
       else
          alert('selected value > 1');
  });
});
```

you form need to have an id for example, in my case `yourform`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FUvBt/)